# Connect redemption API with Outook Store version

Tags: windows, outlook, outlook-redemption

How can we connect Redemption with Outlook 2016 Microsoft store version ? does it work by default ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Redemption supports the Microsoft Store version of Outlook (Outlook Centennial). Use the recently released version 5.18 (see http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/history.htm).

Keep in mind that the MAPI system under Outlook Centennial is very different from the MAPI system under a regular (C2R or MSI) version of Outlook: the client apps (such as Redemption) must load mmgaclient.dll, which, along with mmgaserver.exe, marshals MAPI calls between the client app running as a regular Windows app and the sandboxed version of Outlook and its MAPI system.